# PPRiskComponentDoNotBackupAndSync.plist file

Tags: ios, paypal

My app uses iTunes file sharing as well as the Paypal SDK. When a payment is submitted, a file named "PPRiskComponentDoNotBackupAndSync.plist" appears in the documents folder. Is there a way I can hide/remove this?

Comment: I tried to go about it by using removeItemAtPath, but it keeps on re-appearing. So no at this stage.

Comment: I myself switched to BrainTree API which includes PayPal.